# Is it possible to simulate a temporary network disconnection from inside a Linux container?

Tags: linux, docker, opensuse

### Context

To perform some unit tests on a Linux (openSUSE Leap 15) application that runs on docker I have a manager that sends commands through sockets to app in docker.

### Question

In this context, for some testing I want to be able to send a command to temporarily disable network from inside container, to be clear the command send/reception is not the issue but what I do when I receive such command, I tried `ip link set eth0 down/up` and `down` actually works but not up, here is an example to reproduce, with following docker file:

```
FROM opensuse/leap:15

# We just need ping and ip
RUN zypper --non-interactive --no-gpg-checks --ignore-unknown --no-cd in --auto-agree-with-licenses --allow-unsigned-rpm ping iproute2

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash" ]
```

- Build image with `docker build -t opensuse-leap-15-if-down-up:1.0 .`,
- Run with `docker run -dti --cap-add NET_ADMIN --hostname opensuse-leap-15-if-down-up --name opensuse-leap-15-if-down-up opensuse-leap-15-if-down-up:1.0`,
- Exec with `docker exec -ti opensuse-leap-15-if-down-up bash`,
- From inside container:

  - `ping google.com` to check you can reach it,
  - `ip link set eth0 down` to deactivate eth0 interface,
  - `ping google.com` again to check you cannot anymore: OK, "ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution" error,
  - `ip link set eth0 up` to reactivate eth0 interface,
  - `ping google.com` again to check it is fine: KO, still got "ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution" error.

Any idea why this does not work or idea on how to simulate a temporary network disconnection from inside a Linux container ?

Edit: I also tried `systemctl stop systemd-networkd` without success (`ping google.com` still answers after stop) and I saw there is a `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` too, not sure what it does but stopping it does not disconnect network too.

Edit2: I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909888/11159476) but `route add default gw 172.17.0.1` gives me `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`, and not I had to install `net-tools-deprecated` package to get `route` command what I don't want if possible. But I'm not so familiar with `ip route` commands and for instance `ip r add 172.17.0.1/8 dev eth0` and other tests always gave me `Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length` error.

Final edit: I thought because of my context I was not duplicate of [How to disable and enable internet connection from within Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907073), but finally I am since my answer is inspired from an answer here, I then added a vote to close mine as duplicate.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you ping google.com using its IP address (e.g. `ping 142.251.46.174` or similar with whatever IP address was reported by your earlier `ping google.com` command), does it make any difference?  If so, then the problem is likely DNS-related.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not, I tried both with IP you got (`ping 142.251.46.174`) and IP I got when ping was working (`ping 142.250.179.206`) and both gave me `connect: Network is unreachable` error.

Comment: Have you run `ping google.com` before bringing down the `eth0` interface? Has that worked?

Comment: while this might work but terrible idea to share `/var/run/docker.sock` with containers & running privileged commands on the host via containers. Rogue containers can pollute the `volumes` mounted on `host`.

Comment: If you want that level of control over the network interfaces, you might find a virtual machine easier to work with than a Docker container.

Comment: @harshavmb, yes first ping works, this is on the way to reproduce in my question, and not sure I understand what you say about `/var/run/docker.sock` but I'll look at it. @DavidMaze, this is designed to run on docker because we want several "machines" running at the same time and communicating, with different scenarios with different "machines" states, and docker is just designed for that, using docker compose for each scenario.

Comment: I would go with creating a custom network for the container, and then do `iptables` to block all traffic on that interface from the host. `to reactivate eth0 interface,` what is the output of `ip a` and `ip r` before and after re-activing?

Comment: @KamilCuk, funny I just found an answer around `ip r` (see edit2 in my question), and to answer you, `ip a` are the same before deactivating and after reactivating, but `ip r` is missing `default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0` after reactivating, this is what I can't achieve to do as said in my edit2. OK, just after answering you I tried a simple `ip add r default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0`... and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909888/11159476) in another question that gave me a clue, but `route add default gw 172.17.0.1` does not work for me (gives me `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable` error), finally in addition with @KamilCuk comment in my question I got network again with:

```
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
```

Then I can disconnect with:

```
ip link set eth0 down
```

And reconnect with `up` then `route add` above to simulate a temporary network disconnect.

Edit: after actually using it in docker compose I've seen IP may vary, at least between a launch with `docker run` or `docker-compose up`, I then did a `DisconnectReconnectNetwork.sh` script that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEFAULT_VIA=$(ip r | grep "default via")
ip link set eth0 down
ip link set eth0 up
# Disable https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 (double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting)
# for DEFAULT_VIA since else it is not taken properly by ip route add
# shellcheck disable=SC2086
ip route add ${DEFAULT_VIA}
```

Comment: The answer you linked is by no means a clue rather a warning! Containers shouldn't change nw configuration on hosts. They could easily corrupt hosts & you will have no hosts to run containers!!

Comment: If you want to disconnect network for a short time, try systemctl restarts of either `NetworkManager` or `wicked` directly on the host depending on your linux distro..

Comment: @harshavmb unfortunately there is neither `NetworkManager` nor `wicked` service, due to the fact that this is a docker I think, and as I said in first edit of my answer: "I also tried `systemctl stop systemd-networkd` without success (`ping google.com` still answers after stop) and I saw there is a `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` too, not sure what it does but stopping it does not disconnect network too."